# Node.js Server Process on CentOS 7 shutdown unexpected

Tags: linux, node.js, process, centos7

I do not know if it's really related to CentOS 7. But I deployed My Node.js server on CentOS 7.
The process will shutdown by some reason I don't know unexpected.
I start the server with simple command like:

```
nohup node testServer.js >../testServer.log 2>&1 &
```

If I open the shell with remote SSH client, the server can work for several hours without problem, **BUT** after close the client and jump back the next day, I found there is no such process running.

It's not exception within my node.js Server(At least not any thing can be caught), because I have already set the handler on uncaughtException with correct syntax(tested), but when the process be killed some how, there is nothing in the log file.

So I am guessing it's kind of core dump or external kill, memory leak, etc. 
Then the question is how can I diagnose such issue?
Core dump tool? Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: diagnosis in linux start by logs so try to find the logs maintained by the system   watch the directory    /var/log there you will find some important logs they can help you a lot if its a system error

Comment: Tried to look into /var/log for system error, but did not find any useful info I can dig out.

Comment: did you find any thing suspicious in testServer.log?

Comment: @saurabh, I tried, but I didn't find such file under /var/log or any other path I know.